# Running a Raspberry Pi from a car battery using a Witty Pi 3 (sanity check)

Tags: battery

I'm not totally certain that I understand what a Witty Pi 3 Rev2 does so this is by way of a sanity check that I have got it right.

[The documentation](https://thepihut.com/products/witty-pi-3-rev2) says "Thanks to the on-board DC/DC converter (MP4462), the Witty Pi 3 Rev 2 can accept input voltages up to 28V" but when I read [the user manual](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0176/3274/files/WittyPi3Rev2_UserManual.pdf?v=1614969770) I don't see the power output from the Witty to the Pi. [This review on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcL4ZfRqChQ) is the best I could find and seems to confirm my understanding.

My project, which will probably never pass the vapour-ware stage, is to power a pi on a battery from a child's ride-on jeep and install a web-cam nature-watch on my allotment (a remote site for a vegetable garden with water but no electricity). If I understand correctly then I could even turn the pi off during day-time and so conserve battery power. I want to find what* razes my sweetcorn patch each year and and an optional extra would be to deter the varmints.

Bonus points would be for a device that resembles a fox and wriggles its back-quarters as if it is about to pounce. Even better if it could throw lighted fireworks at them.

* Likely contenders are grey-squirrels, rats, and badgers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Witty Pi HAT outputs power to the Pi via the 5V and GND pins on the 40 pin header connector.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I see that my question now has negative score which means either that I was unclear, or I didn't do research, or it wasn't interesting. I believe I was clear and I included three links so I have to conclude that it was thought uninteresting. I find this rather unwelcoming and won't return. I suggest that the group should collectively rethink its attitude to newbie questions.